# Use of group_concat in a group by

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, group-concat

I am trying to understand the uses of a `group_concat`.
If i do something like:

```
select col1, sum(col2), group_concat(col3), group_concat(col4)  
from table  
group by col1;
```

I will get all the values of `col3` and `col4` in that group in a comma separated list right?
Is this a good use for a group_concat?

Comment: Personally, I find almost no use for GROUP_CONCAT. 9 times out of 10, if I need a concatenated result, it seems more sensible to build it at the application level - particularly when you have functions like PHP's json_encode() which builds a 'concatenated' string from an associative array.

Answer (score 2):

That is the exact purpose of `GROUP_CONCAT`, yes. And your assumption is right. You will get the values from that group for `col3`, `col4` separated by commas (if you don't change the separator).

`GROUP_CONCAT` is an aggregate function that mysql allows you to use, just like `SUM`, `COUNT`, `MAX`, etc. will aggregate the results from the column provided, accoding to the "group" column provided in the `GROUP BY`

More info on the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)